# Which method to setup UIview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview

The cells in my collectionView contains a UIView that should have a shadow. The problem is that if I set the shadow in the cell's AwakeFromNib method the shadow will be applied to the UIView before it has the correct size (which means the shadow will have a different size than the UIView). Which method is called when the cell and all its subviews have been correctly loaded and setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do any UI related work for collection view in this delegate method

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

It will always work